# Run matplotlib plot label, then display error box

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm testing a simple line graph.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import random
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(20,8),dpi=80)
x = range (2,26,2)
y = [15,13,14,5,17,20,25,26,26,24,22,18]
z = [random.randint(20,35) for i in range(12)]
pyplot.xticks(range(2,24,1),rotation = 45,fontproperties = my_font) #rotation旋转度数
pyplot.yticks(range(min(y),max(y)+1))
pyplot.xlabel("")
pyplot.ylabel("")
pyplot.title("")
pyplot.grid(alpha=0.4,linestyle='--')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.plot(x,y, label='111111' ,color='orange',linestyle=':')
pyplot.plot(x,z, label="222222" ,color='#000000',linestyle='-.') # --
pyplot.show()
```

But when I run it, the display of label on top right corner CANNOT display well.
It should display 11111 or 22222 in the box. But it now displays empty box.
How to solve this?
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0kbT.jpg)

Comment: First plot, than call legend

Answer (score 0):

The legend uses the labels defined in the `pyplot.plot()` function. Therefore you first have to plot your data and then call `pyplot.legend()`

Comment: May I ask why you unaccepted the answer then? Just out of curiosity, did it not help?